# CSS vertical Menu - Menu Item Goes to no-hover state on sub-menu hover

Tags: css, menu, hover, drop-down-menu

when i go to an submenu item on... the Item from the main menu goes to no-hover state.. i want it to stay in hover state if i am on its sub-menu...

[take a look at my code here](http://jsfiddle.net/bcvPY/1/)

what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it out, but it should work, if you define the `:hover` on the `li` instead of `a` (however that won't work in IE6).

So instead of

```
a:hover { ... }
```

use

```
li:hover a { ... }
```